# Message-ID contains multiple '@' characters

Tags: email, spamassassin, exim

I am looking at my server's spamassasin and have stumbled across the "problem" that my outgoing email sends out its own X-Report and X-Score in the header (programs used are Outlook 2007 as client and exim4 with the vexim plugin and Spamassasin). On the one hand I want to get rid of the sent X-Report which gets sent out with every email and on the other hand I still want to have it for incoming mails. While I was trying to fix this (which I still haven't) I stumbled across this "error" which makes my email less trustworthy:

```
1.4 MSGID_MULTIPLE_AT      Message-ID contains multiple '@' characters
```

How do I get rid of the multiple '@' characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/Rules/MSGID_MULTIPLE_AT) Outlook 2007 is generating the multiple @s.  Doesn't look like it is something that has been fixed by Microsoft yet...
Concerning tags on your outgoing email, you will need to configure SA not to scan outgoing emails so that you don't send X-Score in the header.  Depending on your MTA type, the configuration for this will be different.  [Here is a link](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mail-archive.com%2Fexim-users%40exim.org%2Fmsg31873.html&ei=T6P5Stv0JIHaNcqz9MsK&usg=AFQjCNHNmSubm24hEhRHSLohcCC3DivGwg&sig2=QNqa5F0O7KK22A6vMDwOjg) that may help